# Cannot assign custom radial for scipy rbf imported in julia through pycall?

Tags: scipy, julia, interpolation, pycall

I have imported `scipy.interpolate.Rbf` from python to `Julia 1.6` using `PyCall`. It works, but when I am trying to assign the radial function value to `multiquadric` it doesn't allow me to do so, due to syntax issue. For example:

```
using PyCall
interpolate = pyimport("scipy.interpolate")

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
z = [1,2,3,4,5]

rbf = interpolate.Rbf(x,y,z, function='multiquadric', smoothness=1.0)
```

for the above example I am getting this error:

```
LoadError: syntax: unexpected "="
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
```

This is due to the use of `function` variable. May I know what can be the way around this error, so that i can assign the `multiquadric` radial for the rbf.

Look forward to the suggestions.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `function` is a reserved keyword in Julia. Additionally, note that `'string'` for strings is OK in Python but in Julia you have `"string"`.

The easiest workaround in your case is `py""` string macro:

```
julia> py"$interpolate.Rbf($x,$y,$z, function='multiquadric', smoothness=1.0)"
PyObject <scipy.interpolate.rbf.Rbf object at 0x000000006424F0A0>
```

Now suppose you actually need at some point to pass `function=` parameter?
It is not easy because `function` is a reserved keyword in Julia. What you could do is to pack it into a named tuple using `Symbol` notation:

```
myparam = NamedTuple{(:function,)}(("multiquadric",))
```

Now if you do:

```
some_f(x,y; myparam...)
```

than `myparam` would get unpacked to a keyword parameter.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!! the first approach worked for me. But I noticed the results from the command `py"$interpolate.Rbf($x,$y,$z, function='multiquadric', smoothness=1.0)"` are not same in python and julia. Any idea why does this happen?

Comment: the tuple idea is really amazing, I am still confused a bit on the syntax implementation will give it a try and update you on my findings! thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have not used this library so this is hard me to say. Perhaps you need to check (in source code of this `Rbf` function) what is exactly expected as `x,y,z`. It might rely on some duck-typing rule that works less perfect when a Julia object is passed.

Comment: I tried the `Named tuple` approach, I would like to suggest a syntax correction in the unpacking function :-> `some_f(x,y; myparam...)`
Thanks again for this amazing suggestion!!

Comment: Thanks - changed comma to semicolon.